# String Input starting at start of a line and terminates with space

Tags: c++

How can i take string input in c++ like the following:
begins at start of line and terminates at first space and ignores what is next to first space on that line and for second string goes to next line,
input is from standard input

example:

```
this is a sample input
here are few lines
looknospaces!
```

string array should conatin

```
string[0]=this
string[1]=here
string[2]=looknospaces!
```

Comment: use `getline()` first, then extract the first word in each line.

Comment: @blackpop You was hurry. The showed solution is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a good approach would be to use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) then extract the first word in each line, otherwise a solution *I don't really like but works* is (ab)using the getline delimiters

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string name, discard;
    std::getline(std::cin, name, ' '); // Takes just the first word (if present)
    std::getline(std::cin, discard); // Takes the rest until \n, discard this
```

then you can join them as you want.